# How to upload video in binary form using facebook API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement post video in my website, using as a parameter a mp4 file in binary form. I am using the endpoint `POST "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos"`, passing as Authorization my access token and as a body the file I would like to upload.

When I hit this call, I get the following error:

```
{
"error": {
"message": "(#100) No permission to publish the video",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100,
"fbtrace_id": "---"
}
}
```

I am familiar with the share dialog solution. However, it is not convenient for my website to post videos as urls and I would like to upload videos only by using binary form. Any idea why this is happening and how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to upload to a user profile or a page? Uploading “normal” videos to user timelines isn’t possible any more, since `publish_actions` permission has been removed. They introduced a new permission `publish_video` - but that is for Live Videos only.

Comment: I am trying to upload video to user timelines.

Comment: Well if they’re not live videos, you can’t.